# Return a tuple from a function and include another value

Tags: lua, luajit

```
function test() return 1, 2 end
function foo()
  return test(), 3
end
```

Expected result: `1, 2, 3`

Actual result: `1, 3`

**LuaJIT 2.1.0**

Comment: It's nice that you want to provide a solution to a problem, but I don't see how anyone would ever find that through search.

Comment: @Piglet Please suggest a better title. Also, I didn't find the solution until after posting here.

Comment: I don't know a better title. I would have changed it otherwise. Anything I can think of is something no one would search for. I don't know. Sometimes I feel that people who do not even bother to at least read the Expressions section of a language's manual do not deserve to know such things :)

Answer (score 3):

@aleclarson answers this question in order to solve this, i want to elaborate why your approach does not work. In lua, multiple return values are possible as are multiple assignments. If you write

```
local a, b = 1, 2
```

this works fine. If you omit any requested values, you will get `nil` (this also happens in arguments to functions). Now functions can return multiple values, which can be mixed with variables in statements like the above. This then looks like your code:

```
local a, b, c = f(), 3
```

This actually truncates the results of f() to **one** result, takes the `3` as **second** value and adjusts with a `nil`, which gets passed to `c`.
See the [lua manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4) for this.

Another way to solve this is to place the function call *at the end*:

```
local c, a, b = 3, f()
```

which admittedly looks a bit strange with the reversed variables order.

Answer (score 2):

```
function foo()
  local a, b = test()
  return a, b, 3
end
```

If you don't know how many return values there are:

```
function foo()
  local tuple = { test() }
  table.insert(tuple, 3)
  return unpack(tuple)
end
```